# Marginal Density Probability using np

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
    P = np.array(
    [
        [0.03607908, 0.03760034, 0.00503184, 0.0205082 , 0.01051408,
         0.03776221, 0.00131325, 0.03760817, 0.01770659],
        [0.03750162, 0.04317351, 0.03869997, 0.03069872, 0.02176718,
         0.04778769, 0.01021053, 0.00324185, 0.02475319],
        [0.03770951, 0.01053285, 0.01227089, 0.0339596 , 0.02296711,
         0.02187814, 0.01925662, 0.0196836 , 0.01996279],
        [0.02845139, 0.01209429, 0.02450163, 0.00874645, 0.03612603,
         0.02352593, 0.00300314, 0.00103487, 0.04071951],
        [0.00940187, 0.04633153, 0.01094094, 0.00172007, 0.00092633,
         0.02032679, 0.02536328, 0.03552956, 0.01107725]
    ]
)
```

Here's the dataset where X corresponds to rows and Y corresponds to columns. I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the Covariance and Marginal Density Probability (MDP) for Y (columns). for the Covariance I have the following.

```
np.cov(P)
array([[ 2.247e-04,  6.999e-05,  2.571e-05, -2.822e-05,  1.061e-04],
       [ 6.999e-05,  2.261e-04,  9.535e-07,  8.165e-05, -2.013e-05],
       [ 2.571e-05,  9.535e-07,  7.924e-05,  1.357e-05, -8.118e-05],
       [-2.822e-05,  8.165e-05,  1.357e-05,  2.039e-04, -1.267e-04],
       [ 1.061e-04, -2.013e-05, -8.118e-05, -1.267e-04,  2.372e-04]])
```

How do I get the MDP? Also, is there a way to use numpy to select just the X and Y vals and assign them to variables where X= P's rows and Y=P's columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data stored in `P` are a little ambiguous. In statistics, the `X` and `Y` have a very specific meaning. Usually, each row refers to one observation (i.e. datapoint) of some statistical object while the column represents a feature that is measured for each statistical object. In your case, there would be `9` observations with `5` features. This is referred to as a [design matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_matrix) `X`, considered exogenous (independent), and serves as the foundation of most statistical learning algorithms. In supervised learning, there is additionally a vector `Y`; its length equals the number of rows in the `X`.

Your task at hand is of unsupervised nature as there is no true exogenous data `Y` and you are interested in the distribution of `X` alone. This opens up additional questions. Indeed, `np.cov()` computes the empirical covariance matrix measuring the pairwise covariance between each of these 5 features resulting in a symmetric `5x5` matrix as you indicated. Asking for the marginal probability density of each column (i.e. feature), however, refers to the univariate distribution of each feature alone. The covariance matrix in between features is irrelevant for this task.

There are several methodologies to obtain estimates of an unknown distribution given some data. Broadly speaking, they fall into two categories: parametric and non-parametric. I'll explain how each methodology works and can be implemented by leveraging NumPy exactly in the way you eluded to.

**1. Parametric density estimation**

In many cases, one assumes that the data stems from a particular parametric distribution. This distributional assumption is mostly based on convenience rather than prior knowledge. Then, estimating the unknown parameter values completely determines the distribution(s). In your case, for example, you could assume that each feature is univariate normal distributed.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

# mere numerical grid to plot densities (no statistical significance)
x_ = np.linspace(0.0, 0.055, 1000)

# estimate mean (mu) and standard deviation (sigma) for each column
mean_vec = np.mean(P, axis=1)
std_vec  = np.std(P, axis=1)

# histograms
for i in range(5):
    plt.plot(x_, stats.norm.pdf(x_, loc=mean_vec[i], scale=std_vec[I]), 
             label='Col. {}'.format(i+1))

plt.suptitle('Marginal Distribution Estimates', fontsize=21, y=1.025)
plt.title('parametric via univariate Normal densities', fontsize=14)
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

[image]

**2. Nonparametric density estimation**

Alternatively, you can use a histogram as a non-parametric estimator of the unknown probability density functions (of each column/feature). Note, however, that you still have to choose a bandwidth `h` that determines the width of the bins. Additionally, non-parametric tools require a larger sample size to provide accurate estimates. Your sample size `9` is likely insufficient.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# endpoints on all bins: implies bandwith h=0.00229
bins = np.linspace(0.0, 0.055, 25) 
h = np.diff(bins)[0]

# histograms
for i in range(5):
    plt.hist(P[:,i], bins, alpha=0.5, label='Col. {}'.format(i+1))

plt.suptitle('Marginal Distribution Estimates', fontsize=21, y=1.025)
plt.title('nonparametric via histograms (h={})'.format(round(h, 4)), fontsize=14)
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

[image]